# Write the most efficient query (SQL+ )?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table where I´m trying to get some information.
 Have been succeeding to get the information but it´s slow.
 Trying to get some other way to do it.
 Wondering if you have some idea.

I want one startdate and one enddate. But I only want them if another tag name has a maximum value of 10 between those date.

what I have done now is to write.
 This code works but not so effecient because it loops 
through allt the possibility.

PLZ help

```
for (select ts as st from history  
    where name='tagg1' and value = '1' and ts between t0 and t1 and request='4')
    do

endDate=(select ts as en from history  where name='tagg2' and ts between st+25:00 and st+40:00 and request ='4' and 
    value='0');

totalsum = (select max from history1 where name='tagg3' and ts between st and endDate )

if totalsum = 10 then
  write st || endDate
end;
```

Comment: You should combine it into 1 sql query to improve performance. Now for each ts from 1st query you execute another 2 queries.

Comment: Ok, but should that query look like, because I dont have a clue about that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    T2.*
FROM
    history1 JOIN
    (
        select 
            T1.start,
            ts as end 
        from 
            history JOIN
            (
                select 
                    ts as start
                from 
                    history  
                where 
                    name = 'tagg1' and 
                    value = '1' and 
                    request = '4' and
                    ts between t0 and t1
            ) T1 ON (history.ts BETWEEN T1.start + 25:00 and T1.start + 40:00)
        where 
            name = 'tagg2' and 
            value = '0' and
            request = '4'
    ) T2 ON (history1.ts between start and end)
WHERE
    history1.name = 'tagg3' AND
    max = 10
```

This query should only return records which are printed in your script by `write st || endDate`.

Comment: problem is that I using a database that doesnt support the WITH statment. So any other suggestions?

Comment: Convert each CTE to inline query. BTW it would be easier if you provided information about what DBMS you use.